# sql3 query, can't understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: sql

I have a database with one table where there are 3 columns. Here's what .schema gives:
.schema

```
CREATE TABLE Frequency (
docid VARCHAR(255),
term VARCHAR(255),
count int,
PRIMARY KEY(docid, term));
```

I am trying a join query to get two specific docid and matching them by term, (sorry if it doesn't make sense, I'm new to sql). I was expecting a table in the format:

```
docid1 |term |count
docid2 |term |count
```

But I'm getting results in the format `docid1 |term |count|docid2 |term |count`
what am I doing wrong?

Also trying to select docid or any other columns instead of doing a select* gives me an ambiguous key error. Here's the query I'm using:

```
 select* from (select docid, term, count from frequency where docid = '10080_txt_crude') as c join (select docid , term, count from frequency where docid = '17035_txt_earn') as d on c.term = d.term;
```

Lastly adding group by docid at the end only gives one answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT docid,term,count
FROM Frequency
WHERE docid=docid1 or docid=docid2
GROUP BY docid,term,count
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `select c.* from ...` to select *all columns from one table*, instead of all columns from all joined tables.

```
select c.* from 
    (select docid, term, count from frequency where docid = '10080_txt_crude') as c 
join 
    (select docid , term, count from frequency where docid = '17035_txt_earn') as d 
on c.term = d.term;
```

Or, maybe you could simplify the syntax further?

```
select c.docid,c.term,c.ount 
from frequency c
join frequency d on c.term = d.term
where c.docid = '10080_txt_crude' and
    d.docid = '17035_txt_earn';
```

The question with that is, **where do you actually use D.**

Are you trying to do `select * from frequency where docid='10080_txt_crude' or docid='17035_txt_earn'`?

---

Joining matching Terms between two DocIDs:

```
select c.docid as c_docid, d.docid as d_docid, c.term, c.count, d.count
from frequency c
join frequency d on c.term = d.term
where c.docid = '10080_txt_crude' and
    d.docid = '17035_txt_earn';
```

This will produce (C DocID, D DocID, Term *(equal in C and D)*, C Count, D Count).

Comment: I'm trying to get docid with those two ids and then listing the ones where the terms match. Executing your code for example gives me the results containing docid 1, but what I wanted was to list the docid's from docid 2 as well right below that satisfy the above condition. Does it make sense? Don't know if I'm explaining clearly.

Comment: If you want results side-by-side, that's SELECT c.*, d.* with a JOIN. If you want results one-above-the-other, that's a UNION. It's easier to find the matches with a JOIN -- SQL expressions can reference columns across a join, but not between rows. Rows are mathematically independent in SQL query & other operations.

Comment: So selct* with a join can only produce results side by side? This was a h/w assignment, I'll keep you posted when i find the right answer. I'm probably missing something.